# Mean value theorem for non periodic complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a non-periodic function.

Let us consider mean value theorem in real analysis.

I know well-known counterexample for complex valued function, $f(x)=e^{ix}$. Since this $f$ is periodic function, I expect that MVT is true for non-periodic function like $f(x)=e^{ix^{2}}$. But I have no idea to prove it true or false. Can anyone give me some opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. You have $f\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)=f\left(\sqrt{4\pi}\right)$, but if $c\in\left(\sqrt{2\pi},\sqrt{4\pi}\right)$, then$$f'(c)\ne0=f\left(\sqrt{4\pi}\right)-f\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right).$$

Comment: What if inequality like $|f(b)-f(a)| \leq C|f'(c)||b-a|$ for every function?

Comment: It is well-known that, if $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is differentiable, then there is some $c\in[a,b]$ such that $|f(b)-f(a)|\leqslant|f'(c)|(b-a)$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you mention some book or reference?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions).